# Send information from Android to SQL Server via JDBC

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc

I am using jtds 1.2.8 plugin to connect to my SQL Server Database.

I have connected successfully and I have created a "Contact Form" where users write down their name, number, date, email etc, and every users info will be stored locally at the app's data.

Now I want to send these data to my SQL Server also via JDBC plugin, I am wondering if it is possible or how can I achieve this using the plugin.

Is there any link or useful information where I can read about this, or a example of a similar solution to this problem.

Thank you for your time.

### EDIT:

This is not a duplicate question of "How to Connect using JDBC" I have asked on how to send data from android to SQL using JDBC, I have mentioned that I already have connected successfully. Please read carefully before answering or making false statements!

Answer (score 1):

You must use Webservice (Rest or SOAP). It is easy and effective

Comment: Thank you Farid for the suggestion.